# Need help understanding how to sort info from text file using java

Tags: java, arrays, file, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to build a program that reads in info from a .txt file, which contains 20 individuals. Each person has four fields, the team they belong to, their batting average, and home run totals. I need to add each individual to their team(4 players to each team), total up the team home run totals, and rank the 5 teams in order. 
I am able to read the text in properly to a single array, consisting of each individual, but I cannot figure out how to also use this data to create a 2D Array. Using the 2D array I would, put the players on the correct teams, and add their home run totals. I want to sort the home run totals from greatest to smallest for each team, and each individual. I am have done my best to find answers, and to learn on other posts and sites, but I am just stumped with the concept of creating 2D arrays and how to sort them.

Updated explanation: 
This is what the info should look like for the single array:

```
 [Team][Name][avg][Home Runs]
```

Then I JUST want to sort the [Home Runs] column, from greatest to smallest, but don't know how to just access that portion of the array.

The 2D array should look like this:

```
  [Team] [Total Team Home Runs]
```

Once again, sorting from greatest to smallest.

Example of the .txt file looks like this:

```
 Team: Name:         Avg:HR:

 MILRyan Braun       .31015
 STLMatt Adams       .28718
 PITSterling Marte   .26420
 CINJoey Votto       .30224
 CUBAnthony Rizzo    .27422
 PITAndrew McCutchen .29522
 MILAdam Lind        .28013
```

The following class reads in the .txt file and puts it in array.

```
  public class ReadTxt {

static String[] teamm = new String[20];
static String[] name = new String[20];
static int[] avg = new int[20];
static double[] homeRuns = new double[20];

static String teams;
static int i;

public void Players(String[] teamm, String[] name, int[] avg, double[] homeRuns){
String[] team = new String[20];


File txtFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Users Name\\Desktop\\homerun.txt");

try{

    Scanner txtScan = new Scanner(txtFile);
    while(txtScan.hasNext()){

        for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            teams = txtScan.nextLine();
            team[i] = teams;
        }
    }

}
catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    System.out.println("File not found" + txtFile);
}

for (i = 0; i < team.length; i++){

    System.out.println(team[i]);
    }
}
}
```

The next class is my attempt at sorting:

```
public class Sort {

static String[] teamm = new String[20];
static String[] name = new String[20];
static int[] avg = new int[20];
static double[] homeRuns = new double[20];
private int index = 0;
private int US = 0;
static double[] homeRunArray;


public void Players(String[] teamm, String[] name, int[] avg, double[] homeRuns){
homeRunArray[index] = ReadTxt.homeRuns[index];
index++;;
US++;
}

public void selectionSort(){
    double temp;
    int min;

    for(int i = 0; i < US-2; i++){
        min = i;
        for(int j=i+1; j<= US-1; j++){
            if(min !=i){
                temp = homeRunArray[i];
                homeRunArray[i] = homeRunArray[min];
                homeRunArray[min] = temp;
            }
        }

    }
}

public void printArray(double[] homeRuns){
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){

    System.out.print(homeRunArray[i]);
    }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remove all that extra code, and state your problem more clearly -- _how to sort a 2D array_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get your question, but I think you are kind of stuck in your 2D-Array problem...

I would recommend you to create a class and implement `Comparable` (or use a `Comparator`). Something like the code below, or even better, make a real `Player` class. This is much easier to understand.

```
public class Sorter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("team"));
            List<SortableLine> lines = new ArrayList<SortableLine>();
            while(scanner.hasNext()) {
                lines.add(new SortableLine(scanner.nextLine()));
            }
            Collections.sort(lines);
            for(SortableLine line : lines) {
                System.out.println(line.line);
            }
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("File not found");
        }
    }

    private static class SortableLine implements Comparable<SortableLine> {
        private String sortCol;
        private String line;

        private SortableLine(String line) {
            this.line = line;
            this.sortCol = line.substring(24, 26);
        }

        public int compareTo(SortableLine other) {
            return sortCol.compareTo(other.sortCol);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, that definitely made this much easier to understand!